# Почему у меня одна переменная в двух адресах? C Language

Tags: c, память, выделение-памяти

Ребят, я когда понял как работает ***Cheat Engine*** я захотел попробовать кое-что сделать. Я уже имею **GNU** компилятор, и создал `.c` файл (***C Language File***). Я сделал такой код:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int cheatEngineDigit = 1;
    printf("%d\n", cheatEngineDigit);
    system("pause");
    cheatEngineDigit++;
    printf("%d\n", cheatEngineDigit);
    system("pause");
    cheatEngineDigit++;
    printf("%d\n", cheatEngineDigit);
    system("pause");
    cheatEngineDigit++;
    printf("%d\n", cheatEngineDigit);
    system("pause");
    cheatEngineDigit++;
    printf("%d\n", cheatEngineDigit);
    system("pause");
}
```

> Что он должен делать?

Он должен объявить переменную **cheatEngineDigit** и присвоить ей число `1`. После чего вывести значение переменной -> дождаться действия пользователя и увеличить переменную **cheatEngineDigit** на единицу. И так по кругу.

Я же тем временем хотел найти адрес этой переменной в ***CheatEngine 7.0***. Я нашёл этот адрес. Но увидел что адрес не один, а два: **0061FF04** и **0061FF1C**. В прошлых РАЗАХ я делал тоже самое, только там адрес **одной переменной** был ***один***. Скажите пожалуйста, почему одна 32-ух битная интовая переменная имеет `два` адреса?

***P.s.: я скомпилировал и запустил .exe файл!***

Comment: она имеет один адрес в пределах одного запуска. В пределах разных запусков она имеет законное право иметь разные адреса. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase-use-address-space-layout-randomization?view=vs-2019

Comment: Ваш  CheatEngine  вообще ничего не знает о том, где находится ваша переменная. Что бы это знать - используют другие программы, чаще все встроеный дебаггер. Он (CheatEngine) тупо ищет. В большинстве случаев - стек часто используется для вычислений. Тут два варианта - 1. ваше число оказалось в стеке вычислений, и второй адрес - адрес в стеке. 2. В "куче" или в памяти просто совпало что какой-то из модулей (в памяти винды ввобще их более 10) сгенерировал такое-же число. Число 1 не такое и редкое число, что бы его не найти. Странно что так мало нашло - наверно маленький диапазон поиска.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш CheatEngine вообще ничего не знает о том, где находится ваша переменная. Что бы это знать - используют другие программы, чаще все встроеный дебаггер. Он (CheatEngine) тупо ищет.

Конкретно в вашем случае - вы ищите по значению, т.к. вы делали операцию со своей еденицей - вы передавали её через стек другой процедуре/функции, которая могла её хранить в своих локальных переменных или передавать в другую процедуру, в результате чего значение вашей переменной оказалось в зоне, которую называют "стековый мусор". Анализировать эту зону сложно, потому что она всегда меняется, у вас она "застыла" благодаря паузе. Но и пауза не стабильна, и один раз стирает данные, а другой раз - нет.

При вызове `printf` будет картина стека такая

```
0061FF04 1 ,тут вызов _сdecl
0061FF08 1
0061FF0c "%d\n"
0061FF10 адрес возврата в main
0061FF14 ebp - cтековое окно
0061FF18 Адрес возврата в printf, или какие-то данные 
0061FF1C 1 аргумент для преобразования double в char, или данные опроса argv
```

Начиная с адреса *0061FF14*, `printf` использует стек ниже на своё усмотрение, не запрещено ей по адресу *0061FF1C* записать копию аргумента.

Дальше при вызове `pause` картина стека станет такой

```
0061FF04 1 ,тут вызов _сdecl
0061FF08 "pause"
0061FF0c адрес возврата в main
-- Спорная граница
0061FF10 адрес возврата в main (возможно данные с прошлого вызова)
0061FF14 ebp - cтековое окно (возможно данные с прошлого вызова)
-- Спорная граница, но гарантия что данные уцелеют - выше.
0061FF18 возможно данные с прошлого вызова
0061FF1C 1 возможно данные с прошлого вызова
```

Надо понимать, что вызов процедуры/функции может привести к тому, что процедура может делать вложеные вызовы, которые используют стек, если вы вызываете процедуру которая хорошо использует стек, а за тем процедуру которая почти ничего не делает - то там где я написал "спорная граница" - могут остаться данные предыдущей процедуры, если новая их не сотрет. Например если `printf` использовала 1 в качестве аргумента что б или перебрать свои аргументы, или что бы преобразовать в строку (преобразования double в char) - она вполне могла "наследить" в стеке, скопировав ваши данные для работы. Команда pause делает несколько вызовов - всегда разное колличество, в зависимости от разных факторов, и может так получится что стек начиная с адреса `0061FF10` может быть не тронут. Т.к. стирание происходит сверху-вниз - то чем ниже по стеку - тем больше вероятность что уцелели данные прошлого вызова.

UDP И даже в том что адрес 0061FF1C её я тоже сомневаюсь, если для 2,3 ситуация повторяется - значит 1-цу,2,3 дублирует printf, если такая ситуация происходит только с 1 - то вполне может быть что в этой области printf хранит к-во аргументов или переменную цикла аргументов, а значение int "1" просто совпадение. В данную версию я больше верю, т.к. локальные переменные printf будут хранится вверху, а их скорее всего много. Но всеравно это "стековый мусор", я так расписал ответ, что б было понятно как он получается.